# is control-d a default stop sign for stdin? in linux C？

Tags: c, linux, terminal

is control-d a default stop sign for stdin?

In our homework, it says command-d will be stop inputting.

Is it a default ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> on Linux terminal with default settings is an end-of-file marker for stdin.

See also [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) and the [stty(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) command (and [termios(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html)...). Use e.g. [feof(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html) *after* some stdio operation, or compare the result of [getc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getc.3.html) with `EOF` (etc....) to detect end-of-file conditions!

Comment: On Windows, Ctrl-Z is translated to EOF. Wish to know why.

Comment: @Jakub: Why does Windows use Ctrl-Z? I think the short answer is "history". From Wikipedia: Early DEC operating systems used this convention, which was borrowed by CP/M, and was later in turn borrowed and continued in the MS-DOS and Microsoft Windows operating systems.

Comment: Yup. But somebody must have made the choice in IBM/Microsoft. 
Anyway, my point was that to underline this was not a C answer, it is platform dependent.