# How do you detect ctrl+D in C?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stdin, eof, fgets

So I read in a line using fgets

```
line = fgets(l, BUFSIZ, stdin);
```

And I from what I understand control+d is EOF so I tried

```
if(line[0] == EOF)
     continue;
```

to get back to the top of the loop. But this led to segfaults... Is there another way?

Comment: From `fgets` man page in Linux: *fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*

Comment: Ctrl-D is operating system specific (unspecified in the C99 standard). On Linux, [Ctrl-D is not a character](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24548128/841108) but generally is an *end-of-file* **condition**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the machine generates `EOF` on <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>, you should be checking `fgets()` for `NULL`, as `fgets()` is obliged to return `NULL` on end of file.

```
line = fgets(l, BUFFSIZ, stdin)
if (line == NULL)
    continue;
```

In your code, you are trying to dereference a pointer that's `NULL` leading to segfault.

Answer (score 1):

Check `feof()` on the stream, or do an extra read and check for `NULL` in `line`.

You're getting a segfault because `line` is `NULL` when you're trying to compare it to `EOF`.